# Bug in the program for finding two strings are anagram or not

Tags: anagram

i wrote the  program to find two strings are anagram of each other or not. here is the code

```
#include<iostream>   
using namespace std;
int main()
{
char a[4]={'a','r','m','y'};
char b[4]={'m','a','r','y'};
int sizea=sizeof(a)/sizeof(char);
int sizeb=sizeof(b)/sizeof(char);
int hit=0;
if(sizea!=sizeb)
{
    cout<<"size not equal;";
}
else
{
    for(int i=0;i<sizea;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<sizeb;j++)
        {
            if(a[i]==b[j]) 
            {
                cout<<'\n'<<"match found"<<a[i];
                hit=hit+1;
                break;
            }

            if(hit==0)
            {
            cout<<'\n'<<"not anagram";
            }

        }

    }
}
return 0;
}
```

but when i'm running it it always shows the output as-

```
    not anagram
    match found a
    match found r
    match found m
    match found y
```

why is it showing "not anagram even when i incremented the hit value?

Comment: @KenWhite why one of loops should run in reverse?

Comment: @mangusta: Doh! Must be getting late here. Thanks.

Comment: That is expected because the first characters of the strings don't match. You should move the check outside of the loop. Even when you move it outside, you will still have bugs. Consider "aaaa" and "army" they will be anagram if you just rely on hit not being 0.